# A standard argument for Penalized-likelihood functions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Im currently studying Fan and Li (2001) on Penalized Likelihood and its oracle properties.
In the proofs they note that the following two statements are standard arguments and I somehow don't understand.
1. $n^{-1}\frac{\partial L(\beta_0)}{\partial\beta_j}=O_p(n^{-1/2})$

2. $n^{-1}\frac{\partial^2 L(\beta_0)}{\partial\beta_j\partial\beta_l}=\mathbb{E}[\frac{\partial^2 L(\beta_0)}{\partial\beta_j\partial\beta_l}]+o_p(1)$

where $\beta_0$ is the true parameter vector and $L(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^n logf(y_i,X_i,\beta)$ with f being the density, which is the same for all y_i.

Remark: I understand the stochastic big O /small O notation and still do not get why this holds.

Comment: I have successfully proved the first statement. Anyone interested may contact me.
The second one is incorrect in my opinion. Theres probably a (1/n) missing in front of the expected value.

Comment: could you please post your arguments as an answer?